# Put html in variable_get and Email

Tags: 7, emails

I am using custom form to store email content using variable_set.
Using drupal_mail and hook_mail to send that content using variable_get.
Now in email I want to add image using html.

```
$pre_body = '<img src="http://sitename.com/sites/all/images/logo.gif" /><div style="padding-top: 10px;">'
$body = variable_get('email_content');
$post_body = '</div>';
$full_body = $pre_body . $body . $post_body;
$message['body'][] = t('@body', array('@body' => $full_body));
```

but in email it shows me...

```
<img src="http://sitename.com/sites/all/images/logo.gif" />
<div style="padding-top: 10px;">Hello obv
You have placed a bid on lot 'AA' of auction 'Test Curator Email'.
You currently the highest bidder.</div>
```

how to achieve it...???

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you using? Are you using any other relevant modules like smtp? (by the way, if people keep answering your questions and you do not accept an answer, it will become increasingly difficult to find people that will answer your future questions)

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need to do is add headers to your email. You can implement a solution like the one that can be found [in this Drupal.org's comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/358855#comment-5826024). The code is pretty much straightforward:

```
$body = '<html><body><img src="http://sitename.com/sites/all/images/logo.gif" />';
$body .= variable_get('email_content');
$body .= '</body></html>';
$my_module = 'foo';
$my_mail_token = 'bar';  // A key to identify the e-mail sent
$from = 'tanvir@gmail.com';
$message = array(
  'to' => '"'.addslashes(mime_header_encode('Winnie Pooh')) .'"<james@gmail.com>',
  'subject' => t('Example subject'),
  'body' => $body,
  'headers' => array(
    'From' => $from,
    'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'text/html;charset=utf-8',),
  );
$system = drupal_mail_system($my_module, $my_mail_token);
  if ($system->mail($message)) {
    // Success.
  } else {
    // Failure.
  }
```

Keep in mind that if your needs for html mailing become more complex and you need to theme your mails using template files or filter the mails' contents after the theme has applied, you can check the [HTML Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlmail) module.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried, But in my case its not working. In logs I am seeing the mail is sent. But I am not getting it in my inbox, nor in spam anywhere. I am wondering if we could do it using drupal_email and hook_mail?

Comment: I am already sending an email using hook_mail and drupal_email. That's working perfect as I am genrating content in code. But here when I have it from DB (variable_get) and add some content using code, it goes wrong.

Comment: its hook_mail and drupal_mail - Correction